# C# execute powershell command

Tags: c#, powershell, c#-3.0

I need to execute the following powershell command in C# :
**get-netconnectionprofile**
if i run the command from PowerShell it returns one record :
[image]

but if I run the following code it returns an empty list.

```
public void CheckWLANNetWork()
{
    using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
        // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
        PowerShellInstance.AddCommand("get-netconnectionprofile"); //

        var test = PowerShellInstance.Invoke(); //here test it is an empty list
    }


}
```

Although, if I run the above method with "Get-Process", for example, it runs just fine.
I am running a X86 app, and my pc is x64. I cannot run my application on x64 due to other tools which runs only on x86. Is there a solution here?

**EDIT:**

As suggested, I called `PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error;`
The error returned is : "Provider load failure".

Comment: What context is your C# code running under (and not working)? Is it running in Visual Studio, or on a website in IIS, or perhaps a Windows Service or Scheduled Task?

Comment: Visual Studio, a unit test. It is a wpf app

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: I am using Windows 8.1

Comment: Why use Powershell? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile.aspx

Comment: You could try the `whoami` command to see what account it is running under.  And then check permissions for that account.

Comment: Because Windows.Networking.Connectivity in not available in .NET Framework 4.5 or higher. It is usable in universal apps, part of .NET CORE

Comment: Steve Wellens, I have admin privileges on my pc. its not a matter of rights I think.

Comment: Are you sure you're not accidentally swallowing an exception here?

Comment: I don`t know in the C# code I receive only an empty list, no error.

Comment: Does PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error contain any errors? If so post them.  Also have you tried manually Importing the NetConnection module?

Comment: `Because Windows.Networking.Connectivity in not available in .NET Framework 4.5 or higher. It is usable in universal apps, part of .NET CORE` Isn't it conceivable that the powershell cmdlet relies on that underlying functionality, and therefore won't work in your universal app? [I am reminded of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32315616/3905079).

Comment: Skuks and Kev you are right, its throwing an error, i will update my question, ty