# How do I download files from the internet in windows7 using powershell

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I have been trying to download files in windows powershell with many commands

Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe' -OutFile 'C:\Users\Nati'

and this was the error

```
The term 'Invoke-WebRequest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or op
ck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try agai
At line:1 char:18
+ Invoke-WebRequest <<<<  'https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe' -OutFile 'C:\Users\Nati\Documents
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-WebRequest:String) [], CommandNotFoundExceptio
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any Ideas about it?

I tried the Invoke-Request method and i thought it would be able to install

Comment: What is your PowerShell version? -> `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315616/the-term-invoke-webrequest-is-not-recoginzed-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet

Comment: Error indicates you do not have Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet installed or it is not on your PSModulePath.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an actual file in `-OutFile` and not a directory.
But as stated in the comments, `Invoke-WebRequest` is only part of PowerShell 3.0 and later.
See [MS Learn - Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-3.0)

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z2201-x64.exe' `
    -OutFile 'C:\Users\Nati\7z2201-x64.exe'
```